# SUM and average

Tags: sql-server

I have table like this

```
ID, Connected, Disconnected
```

I need to calculate how much every id spend time connected, which is easy:

```
SELECT ID,
CONVERT (INT, SUM (
DATEDIFF(second, Connected, Disconnected)))/60.00
```

And I also need to find average connection time (this above divided by count of connections (appearances of IDs) for every ID.

Something like this (which doesn't work)

```
SELECT ID,
CONVERT (INT, SUM (
DATEDIFF(second, Connected, Disconnected)))/60.00,
CONVERT (INT, SUM (
DATEDIFF(second, Connected, Disconnected)))/60.00/(SELECT COUNT ID)
```

How to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:
Add another column to your table and call it Diff (or something) in design mode you set the "Computed Column Specification" to "(datediff(second,[Connected],[Disconnected]))" 
Now you have a column with the computed diff value!

Then you can group without an aggregate or a subquery error :)

```
SELECT ID, AVG(Diff)/60 -- Diff = Your computed column
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ID, AVG(CONVERT (INT, SUM (DATEDIFF(second, Connected, Disconnected)))/60.00)
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I get following error:

Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 51
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.